# Old Binary, New Provisioning Profile?

Tags: iphone, provisioning

Do I really have to rebuild my iPhone application every time I update my ad hoc provisioning profile? The only thing changed is the list of devices allowed to install/run the application.  With other words, it is possible to distribute the old application with the new provisioning profile?

Answer (score 2):

No, you do not have to rebuild the application.

As was stated in a previous answer the problem is the signing, which is something you can do with an existing app bundle, outside of xcode. For more info, the OS X 1.6.4 man page for codesign can be found at http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/codesign.1.html and a little google-fu looking for references to mac console codesigning will get you yet more info.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you do have to rebuild your application. The building process signs the executable with the provisioning profile, so a new profile means you need to re-sign the executable.